# ASP.Net MVC Can't Connect to Database when Getting Role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to write an ASP.Net MVC web application. A few weeks ago I had to reformat my dev PC. When I restored my application I began to get an error that I did not get before. The error comes from trying to get the users role in the razor view. I have enabled the role manager in web.config. I added roles in startup.cs

```
        ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(dbContext));

        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Visitor"))
        {
            var role = new IdentityRole();
            role.Name = "Visitor";
            roleManager.Create(role);
        }
```

and the role is in the database. In my layout I have links in the nav bar that are only available to certain users. The error is thrown when this code is run:

```
                @if(User.IsInRole("Visitor"))
                {
                    <li>Test</li>
                }
```

I have also tried:

```
            @if (Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "Vistor"))
            {
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("VistorArea", "Index", "Toolbox")</li>
            }
```

the errors I get is

> HttpException: Unable to connect to SQL Server database.
>
> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

If I remove the code I can log on and register, so it can connect to the database. I have tried to create a new clean project and have the same issues. I can upload the clean project if it would help. Any assistance is appreciated!

**Update**

So as a response to the question of can I fetch data from the DB. When I run this code:

```
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var test = db.Users.Find("8078ad14-6c09-4c83-baa2-9e14621ceb10");

        if(test.Email == "test@test.com")
        {
            ViewBag.TestString = "Success";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.TestString = "Failure";
        }
```

It succeeds. My Connection string looks like this

```
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-RoleTest-20180707020513.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-RoleTest-20180707020513;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: can you fetch other data from database within this project?

Answer (score 0):

Check your database connectionString from web.config and check IdentityModels.cs

Web.config

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.; Database=Your Database;uid=sa;password=Your Password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

IdentityModels.cs

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
{
}
```